# How to convert formData to a string in an AJAX form?

Tags: ajax, forms, xmlhttprequest, netlify

This is the first time I try to write the functionality of AJAX forms (in vanilla JS). I am hosting the website on Netlify, which doesn't support JSON form data.
So, I am trying to convert the `formData` to a string but obviously I am making something wrong here. 
I am willing to learn and would appreciate if someone could help me understand what I should do to make this code work.

Thanks in advance!

```
const contactForm = document.querySelector("#contact-form");

function sendMessage() {
  const formData = new FormData(contactForm);
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", contactForm.getAttribute("action"), true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  );
  const params = new URLSearchParams(formData).toString();

  xhr.onload = () => {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      console.log("Success!");
      contactForm.reset();
    }
  };

  xhr.onerror = () => {
    console.error("Error!");
  };

  xhrContact.send(params);
}

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  sendMessage();
});
```